# C# reversed ushort

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, endianness

I'm currently having a problem with some Socket stuff.

The output that I want is `0x5801`, which reversed is `0x0158`which is actually 344 as ushort.

```
ushort t = 344;
p.WriteString("\x58\x01", false);
```

I now want to have the variable instead of the hardcoded hex. I already tried with some ReverseBit classes and so on, but nothing really worked.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `p`? Have you tried using a `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader`? They take care of these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start off by *not* using `WriteString`. You want to write *binary* data, right? So either use `WriteShort` or write the bytes directly.

You haven't given much information to work with (like the type of `p`, or what this data is meant to represent) but if this is a problem of endianness, you could consider using my [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) which has `EndianBinaryWriter` and `EndianBinaryReader` which are like the framework `BinaryWriter` and`BinaryReader` classes, but with the ability to specify endianness.

Comment: Hey, `p` is a custom class which adds strings in a row, for packet use.

Comment: @Moritz: So what you're saying is that a class that you haven't shown us doesn't work as you want it to? How did you expect us to help you?

Comment: (Presumably the fact that you've accepted my answer suggests it helped somehow...)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` and `NetworkOrderToHost`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw3e4a0f

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
ushort t = 344;
var b = BitConverter.GetBytes(t);
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(b);
//write b
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of the bytes returned by the [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66) method depends on the endianness of your computer architecture; however, so does the order of the bytes *expected* by [`BitConverter.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx), meaning that you do not have to perform any manual reversing if both operations are performed on the same machine.

```
ushort t = 344;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(t);
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
p.WriteString(hex);
```